# Rails find_all model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am somewhat new to Rails and, in previous smaller applications, I would clutter up controllers with all kinds of junk. I am trying to use Models more effectually and can't really find a good place to learn about Model functions, etc.

I have this model here and I want to find al the `Maps` it `has_many` of so I created this find_maps method.

```
class Subaccount < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
  has_many :users
  has_many :maps

  enum state: { active: 0, inactive: 1 }

  def find_maps
    Map.where(subaccount_id: self.id).all
  end
end
```

In my `subaccounts_controller` I use call this in a variable in a method like so.

```
class SubaccountsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @submaps = Subaccount.find_maps
  end
end
```

So now if I jump over to the show view for that controller and use this code.

```
<% @submaps.each do |sm| %>
  <%= sm %>
<% end %>
```

And then I get this error.

```
undefined method `find_maps' for #<Class:0x007fbe95a3b1e0> Did you mean? find_each
```

Why would I be getting this undefined method find_maps if I am calling it under the sub_account model? I want to make sure I pick up best practices along the way. Can somebody help me out, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because defined in the way you did, this way

```
def find_maps
  Map.where(subaccount_id: self.id).all
end
```

You have to call it on an instance of subaccount. E.g.

- `Subaccount.first.find_maps`
- `Subaccount.new.find_maps`
- `Subaccount.find(some_id).find_maps`

If you want to call it on Subaccount class define it as

```
def self.find_maps
  Map.where(subaccount_id: self.id)
end
```

I removed `.all` that is useless there. You want all maps or you specify a where clause. Both at the same time don't make sense.

Comment: I think you actually do want it to be an instance method. You are getting nil because the Subaccount class does not have an id. Instead, modify your controller code to look up the Subaccount, e.g. `Subaccount.find(params[:id]).find_maps`

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. In this way doesn't make sense because we have a class method but we use `id` in it and we have no instances clearly. I have to understand what the user want to do because I'm confused

Answer (score 0):

Your `find_maps` method actually duplicates a method that ActiveRecord adds for you when you call `has_many :maps`.

In your controller show method, you should look up the Subaccount you are currently showing and call maps on that:

`Subaccount.find(params[:id]).maps`